# IHUAPI.dll fetch only 100,000 Records

Tags: c#, historian, proficy

I am using IHUAPI.dll  in c#.net for fetching records from Proficy Historian Database. It gives me only 100,000 Records.

following is function i am using :

> result= IHUAPI.ihuRetrieveSampledData(handle, tags, start,
>   end,ihuSamplingMode.Trend,0, (uint)interval, out tagValues, out
>   resultError);

I don't understand whether it is limitation of API or missing something ,Also i didn't find any docs related to this.

Anyone has gone through this ..!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that ihuWriteData method has the following note: 
You cannot write more than 100,000 samples at in one call to this function, we can assume that it's API limitation.

Comment: Thanks.. Yes ihuWriteData() has upto 100,000 records for write.But i am Retriving data from Historian, So  not confirm of ihuRetrieveSampledData() method also has Limitations upto 100,000 records.